# Visual Studio 2022 - Combability Mode 1600 error

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I upgraded my SSAS tabular cube project, compatibility mode to 1600 after adding some partitions to my Fact table, however at the deployment I've received this error message :

*Cannot deploy metadata. Reason: Failed to save modifications to the server. The error returned: 'The operation cannot be performed because it references an object or property that is unavailable in the current edition of the server or the compatibility level of the database.*

please help or advise.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/998758/vs-2022-ssdt-ssas-tabular-compatibility-level-1600

Answer (score 0):

After playing with almost all the properties on the Cube I got to nowhere! Finally, I used Git to revert my changes back and I tried to do all my changes one at a time and then Build\Deploy. In the end, I discovered if you do all your Cube project changes and deploy them first and, at the very last step do the Compatibility Mode update to 1600 then deploy again to your server (mine is Azure Analysis Services) it will work out with no errors and can build and deploy.
It's a bug with VS 2022 Compatibility Mode 1600. Hope Microsoft techs before giving a negative point to my question investigate first and then mark a negative point on my question! Please Stop ignoring the question!